# run application from windows 8.1 shell

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

in Win XP and Win 7 i use this in my appication :

```
 LPTSTR path=TEXT("c:\\myApp.exe \"%1\" ");
 RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,TEXT("Directory\\shell"), 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hkey);
 RegSetValue(hkey,TEXT("my application\\command"),REG_SZ,path,wcslen(path));
```

and this is the result [image]
but i windows 8.1 this doesn't work any more .
thanks for your help

Comment: the %1 is the command line given to the application from windows shell . in this case its the path to the selected folder

Comment: should be same, see: http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/08/adding-scan-with-windows-defender-to-the-windows-8-context-menu/

Comment: I don't see any error checking. You really should be error checking, as there's a good chance that UAC is interfering with this

Comment: no this is just an example of use . in the actual code i check if a function succeeded 
also the %1 give the command line to the applcation but the prblem is that when i dblclick it it runs normaly (window shows and everything )
but when i execute it from the shell it runs in the background and consumes muck more CPU than what its supposed to

Comment: So it successfully invokes the program, but it's now running without a window? Have you tried attaching a debugger and seeing (1) how it's invoked, and (2) what it's doing? The fact that the program is still launching, but is now not working is mentioned nowhere in the question.

Comment: sorry didnt mention it in the question also i dont know how to attach a debugger all i know is that with a messagebox() i can show the command line and in taskmgr i can see the process of my  apliction and terminate it 
what i dont understand is why it runs in the background ?!